# Lateral derivative related with integrability at a point in a interval.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $, continuous from right at $ x_0 \in [a,b) $. Proof that $ F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $, defined as $ F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$, is derivable at right of  $x_0$, with $ F'_{+}(x_0) = f(x_0) $.

The question continues with more things, but I think I can continue if someone helpe me to start.

Comment: Can you to explain your ideas about the problem?

Comment: Hi Oliveira, in most of cases in problems that I post here on MathExchange, I post my intuition, part of the solution and such. But unfortunatelly, in this case I don't have a clue in how to approach this. The book says to use the Fundamental theorem of Calculus. I'm writing the definition and the theorems involved here but without a clue. Sorry.

Comment: The only think that I can think of is, if continuos from right we have a sequence  $(x_n) > x_0 $ from right that converges to $x_0$. Also in every neighborhood of points of that sequence we can derive that function  in the points of that sequence, that is we have $ f'(x_n) $ (since is continuous there).

Comment: We also can think that if $ \lim x_n \to x_0 $ we have $ \lim f(x_n) \to f(x_0) $ by the continuity.